# SQL query in eclipse

Tags: java, mysql

I have my connection class like this:

```
public class Codb {

    public static Connection connect() {
        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

            String url = "jdbc:mysql://" +
                    "localhost:3306/bd1";
            String user = "root";
            String passwd = "root";

            Connection conn = (Connection) DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, passwd);

            //Création d'un objet Statement
            Statement state = conn.createStatement();
            //L'objet ResultSet contient le résultat de la requête SQL
            ResultSet result = state.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM consomateur");
            //On récupère les MetaData
            ResultSetMetaData resultMeta = (ResultSetMetaData) result.getMetaData();

            System.out.println("\n**********************************");
            //On affiche le nom des colonnes
            for (int i = 1; i <= resultMeta.getColumnCount(); i++)
                System.out.print("\t" + resultMeta.getColumnName(i).toUpperCase() + "\t *");

            System.out.println("\n**********************************");

            while (result.next()) {
                for (int i = 1; i <= resultMeta.getColumnCount(); i++)
                    System.out.print("\t" + result.getObject(i).toString() + "\t |");

                System.out.println("\n---------------------------------");

            }

            result.close();
                /*state.close();*/
            return conn;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;

    }
}
```

The user enter the id and I want to know if the id is in the database, I created a servletin which I declared this:

```
static Statement St;
public ResultSet rs;
```

and then I have this method that verifies if the id exists or not, but it doesn't work for me.

```
  protected void service(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    String req = "select id from db1.consomateur ";
    try {
        St = (Statement) Codb.Con.createStatement();
    } catch (SQLException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        rs = (ResultSet) St.executeQuery(req);
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


    ResultSet id = rs;

    String un = request.getParameter("id");

    String msg = " ";
    if (un.equals(id)) {
        msg = "Hello " + un + " your login is sucess";

    } else {
        msg = "Hello " + un + " your login is unsucess";
    }

    response.setContentType("text/html");
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    out.println("<font siez='6' color=red>" + msg + "</font>");
}
```

Comment: your comparison is wrong. Why are you matching ResultSet object with String? please refer ResultSet tutorial https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=4&cad=rja&ved=0CD0QFjAD&url=http%3A%2F%2Ftutorials.jenkov.com%2Fjdbc%2Fresultset.html&ei=6ucQU5LFGIPCkwWM9IDIDQ&usg=AFQjCNE5swTf7OU6jvPwsdr3XxolIhSIdw&bvm=bv.62286460,d.dGI

Comment: Exactly my question, your result set is another object. You cannot compare it with string. Get count of results or see if the result set contains the 'un' for login

Answer (score 0):

Two ways to improve your code.

**1.** One simple thing, just iterate over the results in result set and check for the id that you are querying. What your are doing is, you are comparing id (referred as un your code) with result set (referred as id in your code) which is wrong. Result Set is a complex data structure which contains the sql query result data and meta data about it. Your comparison of ResultSet id with query parameter id is wrong. So one way is to iterate over the result set and compare the  value of id of every row with query parameter id value and break the loop when match is found. Example: Taking over from your code

> ```
> ResultSet id = rs;    
> String un = request.getParameter("id");
>
> boolean flag = false;
>
> while (id.next()) { 
>     String i = id.getString("id");
>     if(un.equals(i)){
>        flag = true;
>        break;
>     }   
> }
>
> if(flag){
>   msg="Hello "+ un + " your login is sucess";
> }
> else{
>   msg="Hello "+un + " your login is unsucess";
> }
> response.setContentType("text/html");
> PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
> out.println("<font size='6' color=red>"+ msg+ "</font>");
> ```

So what I did is, i iterate over the result set and for each value of result set, I compared it with query parameter that u sent. If it is matched, I got a hit and I set my flag to true which mean found and I break my loop as there is no point in looking ahead. Otherwise, my loop will eventually end when all the result set entries are exhauted and nothing matches. Therefore, my flag will remain false and later I used that flag variable to set corresponding message for the case.

**2.** The first way is way too time consuming as the number of comparisons happening is far too much if your database contains lot of rows. On  the other hand, if we modify our query a bit and use the sql where clause we can let databse handle the matching and we will enjoy the ease of programming at our end. I hope the id field in db1.consomateur is primary key, then we can use this peice of code to make our life easy.

> protected void service(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse
>   response) throws ServletException, IOException {
>
> ```
> String id = request.getParameter("id");
> String req = "select id from db1.consomateur where id = "+id;
> boolean flag = false;
>
> try{
>
>     Connection c = Codb.connect();
>
>     Statement st = (Statement) c.createStatement();
>     ResultSet rs =(ResultSet)st.executeQuery(req);
>
>     if(rs != null){
>       if(rs.next())
>         flag = true;
>       }
>     }
>
>    if(flag){
>       msg="Hello "+ un + " your login is sucess";
>     }
>     else{
>       msg="Hello "+un + " your login is unsucess";
>     }
>
> catch(Exception e){
> msg = e.getMessage();
> }
>
> response.setContentType("text/html");    
> PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
> out.println("<font size='6' color=red>"+ msg+ "</font>");
>
> }
> ```

So, if query get executed and we have result set not equal to null i.e. we have some data, we can check whether rs contains any rows. Since, id is a primary key, rs will contain only one row and rs.next will point to that row. Therefore, it will be our match and we have set our flag there. Otherwise flag will be false. In this case database itself take care of matching the ids and returning only the matching row to us. So, it will be faster as database create index over primary keys and we need not to create a loop which saves time.

Also, do not make Statement object static in second case as the query for each execution will be different based on id passed as parameter.